# Liberty Server - ClassLoader.getSystemResource returns null

Tags: java, classloader, websphere-liberty

Developed a rest service which uses third party jars. Reviewing their code I found that they are using ClassLoader.getSystemResource("log4j.properties") to retrieve the data. This code returns null and henceforth I get null pointer exception always. The same code if I deploy in websphere 8.5.5.7 and set server classpath it is working fine.
Since I am using Liberty in my local machine this is not retrieving the path.

I also tried setting classloader in server.xml but no use.

```
<library id="config">
  <folder dir="/properties/dev/" includes="*.properties" scanInterval="5s"/>
</library>

<enterpriseApplication id="AbcEAR"location="AbcEAR.ear" name="AbcEAR">
  <classloader privateLibraryRef="config"/>
</enterpriseApplication>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ClassLoader.getSystemResource()` will use the system classloader, which will only be able to see things from the JDK and whatever is on the classpath.  Since Liberty does not use a traditional classpath and instead uses OSGi, the system loader will be of little use in Liberty from an application perspective.

Instead, use `ClassLoader.getResource()` from the thread context classloader, which will take into account the Liberty classloaders.

Comment: Thanks Andy. As I said, I am using third party jars and I do not have access to update the code. I tried to find the class path and place the properties file but still received null.

Comment: @Ctsuser have you tried adding configuring the JVM classpath in jvm.options to add /properties/dev?